# Confluence REST API update issue: Property with name sync-rev is not a String

Tags: rest, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am writing a script to update a confluence page through the REST API, using:

```
curl -u user:password -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"id":173390846,"type":"page","title":"test4","body":{"storage":{"value":"hello world","representation":"storage"}},"version":{"number":10}}' http://confluence.private.com/rest/api/content/173390846
```

but sometimes i get the following error.

```
{"statusCode":500,"message":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property with name sync-rev is not a String"}
```

This can happen if I manually edited and saved the page, or it can happen without the page having been edited manually.
Sometimes if I run the update again it works, and some times it persists and gives the same error.

The script im writing is bigger than the hello world example, but If I created a new blank page, updated it through the REST API, edited it manually, and attempted to update it again (with version incremented) I got the abovementioned error.

I have not found any mention of the property sync-rev other than in this [doc](https://docs.atlassian.com/confluence/latest/com/atlassian/confluence/core/ContentEntityObject.html#SYNC_REV), but it has not helped me in solving my problem.

Our confluence version is 5.9.6

Why am I getting this error, and what can i do/change so that it goes away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same problem and asked for help in the atlassian community. You can follow my question at https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/38379050/how-to-update-confluence-pages-using-rest-api

Further I contacted the support as it seems to me that this problem is a bug at confluence. I will keep you updated with the supports response.

Edit: This is what Atlassian suggests:

> 1. backup the database since this require manual database delete
> 2. run the following SQL query:
>      // identify how many entries need to be deleted
>      select count( distinct propertyid) from CONTENTPROPERTIES where propertyname='sync-rev';
>      // delete all of the entries
>      delete from CONTENTPROPERTIES where propertyname='sync-rev';
> 3. restart Confluence instance
> 4. verify if the problem persist

Please note that I have not verified their solution yet.

Comment: As these properties tend to be created even on new pages I assume they will be recreated after you did a cleanup. Thus I don't think this is a solution. Sounds more like a workaround.
Any news on a fix?

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved with version 5.9.14: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-41493